# What is the difference between these two answer?

Tags: java, algorithm

I finish a question "balanced binary tree", and here are the two versions I coded. The first is the one accepted, and the other is the one failed. The difference is the position of "+1", when I put it in return statement, the algorithm passed.

But why can't I put it in assignment statement?

And the failed testcase is this one:

Input: [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4]
Output: true
Expected output: false
(I have no idea how this array is transformed into a binary tree.)

Definition for a binary tree node.

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode (int x) { val = x;}
}
```

Here are the algorithms:

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if(depth(root) == -1)
        return false;
    else return true;
}

// algorithm 1
private int depth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    int leftdepth = depth(root.left);
    int rightdepth = depth(root.right);
    if(leftdepth == -1 || rightdepth == -1 || (Math.abs(leftdepth - rightdepth) > 1))
        return -1;
    else
        return Math.max(leftdepth,rightdepth) + 1;

// algorithm 2
private int depth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    int leftdepth = depth(root.left)+1;
    int rightdepth = depth(root.right)+1;
    if(leftdepth == -1 || rightdepth == -1 || (Math.abs(leftdepth - rightdepth) > 1))
        return -1;
    else
        return Math.max(leftdepth,rightdepth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you're comparing the values with -1. The first algorithm would be the same as the second if you would make it:

```
if(leftdepth == 0 || rightdepth == 0 ...
```

Comment: The comparison with `-1` is to ensure both branches are balanced.

Comment: yes, but because the code already adds 1 to it, the magic value is not -1 anymore but it is 0. Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: No you are not missing something - you are correct. I missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm 1 is correct because the depth of a branch is the sum of the depths of it's sub-branches plus `1` (this node).

Algorithm 2 is not correct because it will record the depth of a `null` node as `1`.